# C++: Handling composition classes

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, containers, composition

I'm actually learning game programming using inheritance but it's really getting annoying when my derived classes are getting more and more complex.

I've heard about composition classes and how it was simpler to just "plug-in" feature classes into handling classes but I have problems using this with containers.

If I want to add a lot of different objects using inheritance, I would create many derived classes (Object1, Object2, Object3) using the same base class (Entity) and keep track of them using a vector.

Ex:

```
class Game
{
public:
                Game();
                ~Game();
    void        initialize()    { mEntities.push_back(new Object1);
                                  mEntities.push_back(new Object2);
                                  mEntities.push_back(new Object3);

                                  for(int i(0); i < mEntities.size(); ++i)
                                      mEntities[i]->initialize();
                                }

    void        update(float dt){ for(int i(0); i < mEntities.size(); ++i)
                                      mEntities[i]->update(dt);
                                }

    void        render()        { for(int i(0); i < mEntities.size(); ++i)
                                      mEntities[i]->render();
                                }

private:
    vector<Entity*> mEntities;

};
```

Now using composition classes, I can't find out how to keep track of different objects without going back to inheritance. 
Right now that's what I've come up using composition :

```
// I create "feature" classes
class Drawable
{   /* ... */
};

class Movable
{   /* ... */
};

class Destroyable
{   /* ... */
};

// Then the object classes
class Object1
{
private:
    Drawable    drawable;
    Movable     movable;

};

class Object2
{
    /* similar stuff... */
};
```

Now my objects do not have a common base class and I do not understand how I would handle them without creating them individually.

My question is, what I am supposed to do to loop through many different objects that doesn't have a common base class?

Thanks

Comment: Inheritance has a lot of dessign ([and performance](http://research.scee.net/files/presentations/gcapaustralia09/Pitfalls_of_Object_Oriented_Programming_GCAP_09.pdf)) problems. I think a better solution to big projects is to use component dessign instead of OO-inheritance-based dessigns. Regardling in your problem, I suggest you to read about mixins. They are a good tool to attach (plug-in) features into an existing class.

Comment: Also consider to stop using raw-pointers (Manual-memory-management in general) and use smart pointers instead of that.